# get the value of OnMessage() websocket

Tags: java, javascript, websocket

I'm using websocket in the client side (javascript) and in the server side a java class.

This is my `WordgameServerEndpoint` side class

```
@ServerEndpoint(value = "/socket")
public class WordgameServerEndpoint {

private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());

@OnOpen
public void onOpen(Session session) {
    logger.info("Connected ... " + session.getId());
}

@OnMessage
public String onMessage(String unscrambledWord, Session session) {
        logger.info("Starting the game by sending first word");
    return unscrambledWord;
}

@OnClose
public void onClose(Session session, CloseReason closeReason) {
    logger.info(String.format("Session %s closed because of %s", session.getId(), closeReason));
}

}
```

This is the WebSocketServer class

```
public class WebSocketServer {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    runServer();
}

public static void runServer() {
    Server server = new Server("localhost", 9988, "/websockets", WordgameServerEndpoint.class);

    try {
        server.start();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.print("Please press a key to stop the server.");
        //reader.readLine();
        System.out.println(reader.readLine());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        server.stop();
    }
}
}
```

and this is my javascript function to send message

```
   $scope.savedata=function(){

             socket= new WebSocket('ws://majed-PC:9988/websockets/socket');
              socket.onopen= function() {
                 socket.send('hello');

              };

  };
```

How do I get the value of the sent message on the server side?

Answer (score 1):

See

```
@OnMessage
public String onMessage(String unscrambledWord, Session session) {
    logger.info("Starting the game by sending first word");
    return unscrambledWord;
}
```

on server side. `unscrambledWord` is the received message. Your implementation just echoes it back, which might not be what you want to do - just place your logic there.